# Set active state using css classes when click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of checkboxes in my react aplication.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Checkbox, Row, Col } from "antd";
const items = [
  {
    value: "A",
    label: "A"
  },
  {
    value: "B",
    label: "B"
  },
  {
    value: "C",
    label: "C"
  },
  {
    value: "D",
    label: "D"
  },
  {
    value: "E",
    label: "E"
  }
];

const Test = () => {
  const [actives, setActives] = useState(["A", "C"]);
  function onChange(checkedValues) {
    console.log("checked = ", checkedValues);
    setActives(checkedValues);
  }
  return (
    <Checkbox.Group style={{ width: "100%" }} onChange={onChange}>
      <Row>
        {items.map((i) => {
          return (
            <Col className={actives.includes(i.value) ? "active" : ""}>
              <Checkbox value={i.value}>{i.label}</Checkbox>
            </Col>
          );
        })}
      </Row>
    </Checkbox.Group>
  );
};
```

By default some of checkboxes are checked: `const [actives, setActives] = useState(["A", "C"]);`. For checked checkboxes i use `active` class `className={actives.includes(i.value) ? "active" : ""}`. The idea of the application is next:

1. When user will select another checkboxes than these that are `active`, the active checkboxes don't have to be disabled like now.
2. If use click on the checkbox that is already active, from that checkbox we should romoved `active` class.
3. At the end user should be able to add active class to all checkboxes but to take into account the previous checkboxes that already are `active`.

    Question: How to achieve this? 
   demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/use-with-grid-antd4123-forked-5kku2?file=/index.js:0-937

Comment: Can you elaborate on "When user will select another checkboxes than these that are active, the active checkboxes don't have to be disabled like now." The active checkboxes won't be checked?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only problem with your codesandbox is that, when first clicking any checkbox, the previous state ("A" and "C" checked) was ignored - so just the clicked checkbox would be checked (whether or not it was initially checked), and all others would be unchecked.

After that it all works as I imagine you would want.

And the reason for the bug was simply that there was a discrepancy between your `actives` state and which checkboxes in the group were internally considered to be checked. Your code uses `actives` to determine CSS classes, but not the initial state of what is checked - so `checkedValues` was starting off empty.

The fix is simple, pass the `value` prop to the Checkbox Group component, as documented [here](https://ant.design/components/checkbox/#Checkbox-Group). Your `actives` is already the correct format, so simply adding the prop `value={actives}` fixes the problem.

Comment: could you help please? https://codesandbox.io/s/use-with-grid-antd4123-forked-5kku2?file=/index.js  value does not work

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to assign an initial value to checkbox group, like this:

```
<Checkbox.Group style={{ width: "100%" }} onChange={onChange} value={actives}>
```

That should sync state of your checkboxes with `actives` initial value

And here, this is how you can achieve 3rd point - 'check all' functionality

```
const Test = () => {
  const [actives, setActives] = useState(["A", "C"]);
  const [checkAll, setCheckAll] = React.useState(false);

  function onChange(checkedValues) {
    console.log("checked = ", checkedValues);
    setActives(checkedValues);
  }
  const onCheckAllChange = e => {
    setActives(e.target.checked ? items.map(option => option.value) : []);
    setCheckAll(e.target.checked);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Checkbox.Group style={{ width: "100%" }} value={actives} onChange={onChange}>
        <Row>
          {items.map((i) => {
            return (
              <Col className={actives.includes(i.value) ? "active" : ""}>
                <Checkbox value={i.value}>{i.label}</Checkbox>
              </Col>
            );
          })}
        </Row>
      </Checkbox.Group>
      <Checkbox onChange={onCheckAllChange} checked={checkAll}>
        Check all
      </Checkbox>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: i changed my code and i wrap it into a Form, and it does not work, could you help? https://codesandbox.io/s/use-with-grid-antd4123-forked-5kku2?file=/index.js

Comment: You need to wrap it in other `<Form.Item..` than the username field. If you wrap it into a Form, then you can move initial values for Checkbox.Group to initialValues prop of a Form tag. Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/use-with-grid-antd4123-forked-40gpu?file=/index.js

Comment: do you know a solution changing the state in react? To compare the values or something like this? Because in my application is something wrong. Thanks