# Change state in react according to a condition

Tags: reactjs

I have the next situation in my react js application:
I have the next situation in JavaScript:

```js
    const [arr1, setArr1]= setState([1,2,3]);  // by default it is empty []
    const [arr2, setArr2]= setState([2,1,8,9]);
```

`arr1` can be changed dynamicly. So sometimes it could be `[1,2,3,4]` or `[4,2,3]` and so on. The idea is next:

Depending by the `arr1` to change the `arr2` like, if in `arr1` is a number which is equal with a number from `arr2`, then the number from `arr2` that is equal should be deleted, but if the new number that is added in `arr1` is not exists in `arr2` then it should be added in `arr2`:

EX:

1. `arr1 = []; arr2=[2,1,8,9] // nothing happens`
2. `arr1 = [1]; arr2=[2,8,9] // 1 from arr2 is deleted`
3. `arr1 = [1,8,9,7]; arr2=[1,2,7] // 1,8,9 from arr2 is deleted, 7 is added`

Who can help? How to create conditions in react application to change the state properly?

Comment: Don't mean to be rude, but this is incomprehensible: *Depending by the arr1 to change the arr2 like, if in arr1 is a number which is equal with a number from arr2, then the number from arr2 that is equal should be deleted, but if the new number that is added in arr1 is not exists in arr2 then it should be added in arr2*

Comment: Besides, you have already asked an identical question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66377574/compare-array-and-change-if-values-are-different Voting to close.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare array and change if values are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66377574/compare-array-and-change-if-values-are-different)

Comment: @codemonkey, could you help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66375156/set-active-state-using-css-classes-when-click

Answer (score 0):

You want `useEffect` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Heres some sample code for the delete part, you can add a case in the forEach for add

Note: I did not run this code to check for errors

```
useEffect(() => {
  let arr2Copy = [...arr2]
  arr1.forEach(i => {
    const index = array.indexOf(i)
    if (index > -1) {
     arr2Copy.splice(index, 1)
    }
  })
  setArr2(arr2Copy)
}, [arr1]) // Only re-run the effect if arr1 changes
```

Comment: could you help please with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66375156/set-active-state-using-css-classes-when-click , How to implement your answer here? Thanks a lot, it will be very helpfl.